# I Need this code only in joins with out subqueries while using joins it showing different values

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql-server, jquery-ui

```
SELECT q.vQuestionTitle,a.NumberOfAnswers,qv.NumberOfViews FROM questions q
inner join (SELECT iQuestionid,count(iQuestionId) as NumberOfAnswers FROM answers group by iQuestionid) a on a.iQuestionid=q.iQuestionid
inner join (SELECT iQuestionId,count(iQuestionId) as NumberOfViews FROM question_views group by iQuestionId) as qv on qv.iQuestionId=q.iQuestionid
where q.vQuestionTitle like '%how%'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: i asked for how can we convert a code from sub queries to joins

Comment: You need to show the efforts you put forward to solve this problem on your own, and ask about the specific difficulties/errors you're facing.

Comment: Add some efforts to your question (Add Input data and Output result to your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `Distinct` clause inside `Count` aggregate function.

Because there is no table structure mentioned for all three tables in your query, So, my answer totally depends on my assumption. I am pasting my query below because it helps me -

```
declare @questions table (iQuestionid int,vQuestionTitle varchar(max))
insert into @questions select 100,'How are you?'
select * from @questions

declare @answers table (iQuestionid int, Answers varchar(max), Participant_id int)
insert into @answers select 100, 'I am good.', 1001 union all select 100, 'I am fine.', 1002
select * from @answers

declare @question_views table (iQuestionid int, viewer_id int)
insert into @question_views select 100, 1001 union all select 100, 1002 union all select 100, 1003
select * from @question_views

SELECT
    q.vQuestionTitle,
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.Participant_id), 
    COUNT(DISTINCT qv.viewer_id)
FROM @questions q
inner join @answers a on a.iQuestionid=q.iQuestionid
inner join @question_views qv on qv.iQuestionId=q.iQuestionid
where q.vQuestionTitle like '%how%'
group by q.vQuestionTitle
```